# Почему после автозаполнения input регулярка выдает неверное значение?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Что-то никак не могу понять, что не так.

Есть поле input куда вводится сумма. После того как ввели значение сумма у меня преобразовывается вот так

```
const newVal = value.Amount.toString().replace(/\s/, '').replace(/,/g, '.');
```

В дальнейшем как в работу вступает валидатор, который проверяет по регулярке, условие, регулярка вот такая:

```
/^(\d+\.|\d*[1-9])\d*$/.test(newVal)
```

При вводе "руками" скажем числа 111,00 значение преобразовывается в 111.00 и все ок, это больше нуля, регулярка отдает true. Но если ввести значение в поле через автокомплит, то тогда тест регулярки отдаст false и тогда валидатор сработает и скажет, что число 111,00 должно быть больше нуля. Что не так делаю?

Замечу, что мне в `value.Amount` приходит строка. Поэтому мне без разницы когда приводить значение к точке.

Comment: А на какое событие вы повесили обработчик?

Comment: Когда вводится значение, срабатывает handleChange, в которое и отправляется значение поля в виде объекта. Получается если выбраем сумму через автокомплит, то тогда прилетает сумма целиком как 111,00. Пробовал делать вот так даже replace(/\s+/g, ''), но не помогает